# How to group consecutive integers in an array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to split integer list into sublist and then return a `std::map<int, string>` to map the `int` to the `string` joined by sublist?

It is necessary to ensure that each sublist is monotonically increasing with consecutive values

Example

```
input:
{1,2,3, 6,7,8,9, 12, 14,15}

output:
1  -> "1-2-3"
2  -> "1-2-3"
3  -> "1-2-3"
6  -> "6-7-8-9"
7  -> "6-7-8-9"
8  -> "6-7-8-9"
9  -> "6-7-8-9"
12 -> "12"
14 -> "14-15"
15 -> "14-15"
```

I tried this code and make it right, thank everyone providing idea

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void split(int* lis, int num, map<int, string> &dict)
{
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        string str = to_string(lis[start]);
        for (int j = start + 1; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (lis[j] - 1 == lis[j - 1])
            {
                end = j;
                str = str + "-" + to_string(lis[j]);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
            dict[lis[j]] = str;
        start = end = end + 1;
        if (end == num)
            return;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int lis[10] = { 1,3,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,19 };
    map<int, string> dict;
    split(lis, 10, dict);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << lis[i] << "\t" << dict[lis[i]] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to split by?

Comment: Build a adjacency difference sequence. I.e. 1,1,3,1,1,1,3,2,1 From that, determine what each cluster will look like. Good luck.

Comment: Please show any attempt you have made to solve this problem. Please explain why you are stuck. Requests to do homework don't get much response unless you can show that you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: Have two indexes: Start of sequence, and end of sequence. Begin by setting the start of sequence index to `0` (the first index in the "list") and then iterate over the list using the end of sequence index. If the difference between the current element (as indicated by the end of sequence index) and the next element is larger than `1` then you have a full sequence indicated by the start and end of sequence indexes. Store in in some suitable way, and set both start and end of sequence indexes to the next element, and continue.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  Thank you for providing a good idea!

Comment: @partida. After you edited your question, I now adapted my answer. You had no source code before and I could not see your function prototype. Now, my new function prototype and main, are exactly the same than in your example. And basically my answer implements the statement from  Some programmer dude but was given 2 minutes before his comment. Anyway. Everybodys good comment is very welcome and we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice example for the usage of STL containers and algorithms.

So, we could start with a `std::vector` of any values. This, we can sort and remove the duplicates by putting it into a `std::set`.

Then we iterate over this data and use `std::adjacent_find` to look for a value that is not equal to the previous value + 1. This we can do in a loop until we reach the end of the original data.

Everytime, when we found the end of such a sequence, we will build the resulting specified string and store it, together with the source data in a `std::map`.

We set the start iterator to the current end iterator and continue to search.

At the end, we show the result to the user.

Of course there are many possible solutions. Please see one example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    // Some test data. Not sorted, with duplicates
    std::vector testData{ 15,14,12,14,3,3,12,1,7,8,7,8,9,2,1,1,6,6,9,15 };

    // Sort and remove duplicates. Maybe you wanna do this or not. Up to you. If not, eliminate that line and work with original data
    std::set data(testData.begin(), testData.end());

    // Here we will store the result
    std::map<int, std::string> result{};

    // We will start the evaluation at the beginning of our data
    auto startOfSequence = data.begin();

    // Find all sequences
    while (startOfSequence != data.end()) {


        // FInd first value that is not greate than one
        auto endOfSequence = std::adjacent_find(startOfSequence, data.end(), [](const auto& v1, const auto& v2) {return v2 != v1 + 1; });
        if (endOfSequence != data.end()) std::advance(endOfSequence, 1);

        // Build resulting string
        std::ostringstream oss{};
        bool writeDash = false;
        for (auto it = startOfSequence; it != endOfSequence; ++it) {
            oss << (writeDash ? "-" : "") << std::to_string(*it);
            writeDash = true;
        }

        // Copy result to map
        for (auto it = startOfSequence; it != endOfSequence; ++it)
            result[*it] = oss.str();
        
        // Continue to search for the next sequence
        startOfSequence = endOfSequence;
    }
    // Show result on the screen. Or use the map in whichever way you want.
    for (const auto& [value, text] : result) std::cout << std::left << std::setw(2) << value << " -> """ << text << """\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I am using CTAD, so you have to compile with C++17 enabled.

Developed, compiled and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally compiled and tested with gcc10.2 and clang 11.0.1

---

**EDIT**

Meanwhile OP posted own code. I adapted my function to that style.

But in C++ we should **never** use C-Style arrays and especially not `using namespace std;`

Anyway. Please see solution below.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


void split(int* lis, int num, std::map<int, std::string>& dict) {

    // We will start the evaluation at the beginning of our data
    auto startOfSequence = lis;
    auto endOfList = lis + num;

    // Find all sequences
    while (startOfSequence != endOfList) {

        // FInd first value that is not greate than one
        auto endOfSequence = std::adjacent_find(startOfSequence, endOfList,
            [](const auto& v1, const auto& v2) {return v2 != v1 + 1; });
            if (endOfSequence != endOfList) std::advance(endOfSequence, 1);

        // Build resulting string
        std::ostringstream oss{};
        bool writeDash = false;
        for (auto it = startOfSequence; it != endOfSequence; ++it) {
            oss << (writeDash ? "-" : "") << std::to_string(*it);
            writeDash = true;
        }

        // Copy result to map
        for (auto it = startOfSequence; it != endOfSequence; ++it)
            dict[*it] = oss.str();

        // Continue to search for the next sequence
        startOfSequence = endOfSequence;
    }
}

int main() {
    int lis[10] = { 1,3,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,19 };
    std::map<int, std::string> dict;
    split(lis, 10, dict);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << lis[i] << "\t" << dict[lis[i]] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Suman Bhadra: You tried to edit my code and add "<int>" to the ````vector```` and ````set````. With C++17 this is not necessary. The compiler will deduce the correct data type. That is called CTAD. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another solution for this problem, which will give the same results but with a better performance for large input data.

for example , imagine your input array is an array of size `100000` integers inside which are all consecutive i.e `[1 , 2 , 3 , ... , 100000]`

So by the method you need to store your data by you will have a string of around `200000` characters stored `1e5` times in the map this with no doubt will crash during runtime (`O(n^2)` memory complexity)

So instead of making the value of the array element to be the key of the map , you can before that make a key for each array value depending on the sequence it's located at , then you can retrieve the sequence by `sequenceOf[keyOfValue[arrayValue]]` which will result in `O(n)` memory complexity where `n` is the size of the array.

Code example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>  
using namespace std; 

string convert_to_string(vector<int> sequence){
    string ret = "" ; 
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sequence.size() ; i++){
        ret += to_string(sequence[i]) ;
        ret += "-";
    }
    ret.pop_back() ; 
    return ret ; 
}

int main(){

    int a[] = {1,2,3, 6,7,8,9, 12, 14,15}; 
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) ; 
    
    map<int , string>mp ;
    map<int , int>keyOfValue; 
    vector<int>sequence; 
    int key = 0 ; 
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        
        if(sequence.empty() || sequence.back() + 1 == a[i]){
            sequence.push_back(a[i]); 
            
            if(i != size - 1)
                continue ;
        }
        
        for(int j = 0 ; j < sequence.size(); j++){
            // store all sequence element keys to be the same 
            keyOfValue[sequence[j]] = key ; 
        }
        
        // store the sequence only once. 
        string value = convert_to_string(sequence); 
        mp[key++] = value ; 
        sequence.clear(); 
        
        if(i != size - 1)
            i--; 
    }
    
    // How to retrieve the value 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        cout << mp[keyOfValue[a[i]]] << endl ; 
    }
}
```

Also instead of using `std::map` to store the sequence you can use a `std::vector<string>` to also reduce the retrieving of the array time from `logarithmic` to `O(1)` time, however I have use `map` as this was the goal of the question.